# Storing texts from many files in an array using foreach Perl

Tags: perl

```
sub open_file {
    my @files = @_;
    my @file_text = ();

    foreach my $file(@files){
        open(my $fh, '<', "./DATA/" . $file) or die "can't open $file: $!";
        @file_text = <$fh>;
        close($fh);
    }
    print "@file_text";
}
```

Having problems concatenating texts from 3 different `.html` files into one array `@file_text`

So far the script only stores the text into `@file_text` from the very last `.html` file it loops through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, as you erase the last value of @file_text each time with the line

```
@file_text = <$fh>;
```

you should replace this line with

```
push (@file_text, <$fh>);
```

Comment: thank you i figured but i am beginner so i didnt know how to solve it :)